# Get entity object's property names excluding entitycollection and entityreference

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am working on a method that compares two objects using reflection. The object types are objects created from entity framework. When I use GetProperties() I am getting EntityCollection and EntityReference properties. I only want the properties that belong to the object and not any associated properties or references from foreign keys.

I've tried the following [How to get all names of properties in an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851274/how-to-get-all-names-of-properties-in-an-entity).

I thought about passing an array of properties to compare but I don't want to have to type them in for each object type. I am open to some suggestions even those that don't use reflection.

```
public bool CompareEntities<T>(T oldEntity, T newEntity)
{
    bool same = true;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        var oldValue = property.GetValue(oldEntity, null);
        var newValue = property.GetValue(newEntity, null);

        if (oldValue != null && newValue != null)
        {
            if (!oldValue.Equals(newValue))
            {
                same = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if ((oldValue == null && newValue != null) || (oldValue != null && newValue == null))
        {
            same = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return same;
}
```

Comment: Are these entities POCOs or derived from `EntityObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the suggestions from @Eranga and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381986/1129035 I was able to come up with a workable solution.

Since some of the properties in the root object are a GenericType there needs to be two different if statements. Only if the current property is an EntityCollection skip over it.

```
public bool CompareEntities<T>(T oldEntity, T newEntity)
{
    bool same = true;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(pi => !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject)))
        && !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityReference)))
        ).ToArray();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        var oldValue = property.GetValue(oldEntity, null);
        var newValue = property.GetValue(newEntity, null);

        if (oldValue != null && newValue != null)
        {
            if (!oldValue.Equals(newValue))
            {
                same = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if ((oldValue == null && newValue != null) || (oldValue != null && newValue == null))
        {
            same = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return same;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering out `EntityObject` type and `EntityCollection` properties.

```
var properties = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperties().
                   Where(pi => !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject))
                   || pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityCollection));
```

Comment: EntityCollection requires a type to be set.

Comment: Sorry trying to figure out stackoverflow :) I changed to this: `PropertyInfo[] properties = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(pi => !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject)))                    && !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityReference)))).ToArray();` Now only EntityCollections need to be excluded.

Comment: My question now is how to remove the EntityCollection objects from the property list

Comment: @curiousg modify the `Where` condition to filter out `EntityCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

make it easy for yourself and do this instead

PropertyInfo[] properties = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperties(pi=> pi.PropertyType.NameSpace=="System").ToArray();

Comment: you rock. This fixed my own issue :)