# Look for value in property of Object with out knowing the name of the property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, object

I have a Bank Object that has several nested objects/properties/methods as well as wrapping around a com object. There is limited documentation to this lib and I want to change the Banking Number in the Object but I have no idea what property's name is, or how far down in the object tree. However I do know the value of the property is 1231241. How can I search a object for that value to find it and change it ?

I have tried:

- digging through the watch window, but the object is huge
- [Bug Aid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36925113-cdce-4953-a5d6-fb3d2912dad7) this is still in beta and it stopped working
- [Object Compare](http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/releases/view/47978) but this didn't work well I think because of the com object

I might just have to get my hands dirty and dig through the watch window but I thought I would see if anyone has any ideas. I am looking for a utility to do this with.

Comment: What about using `Reflection`? Maybe you can itare through all the propertiers looking those values without the need to know the names.

Comment: Is there a utility to do that with ?

Comment: I don't think so, you'll need to write your own code to inspect the object. This thread maybe be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381851/how-to-recursively-iterate-over-properties-of-an-entity

Comment: I'm the co-creator of BugAid. By "stopped working", do you mean your trial period ran out, or that you experienced some problem with it? Please let us know through our [Contact Page](http://www.bugaidsoftware.com/support/) so we could help fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I increased the level to dig to 10 and it would only dig to 3. I will let you know through the contact page

Comment: Also is there any log files I can look at to see if BugAid throwing a exception

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Yes, the log files are at %TEMP%\BugAid\Logs, if you have any problems, please send those log files to us at info@bugaidsoftware.com so we could help and figure out what went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @OmerRaviv I sent the logs this morning along with two error reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that I created using `Reflection` that maybe can help you:

```
private static void recurseAndFindProperty(Object obj) {
   foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
       if ((pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))) {
           IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)pi.GetValue(obj, null);

           foreach (object val in collection)
               recurseAndFindProperty(val);
       } else {
            if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(Descendant))
                if ((int)pi.GetValue(obj, null) == 1231241)
                    pi.SetValue(obj, 10, null)); // Change the value.
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Good Suggestion didn't find what I was looking for (I know the value is in the object its in the object)

Comment: I think there is a bigger issue than this code Thanks for the help Erick